# Как сделать чат в реальном времени?

Tags: php, html, webrtc

Как сделать такой чат, **НО** это не общая комната для пользователей, а нужно сделать так, чтобы соединялось два пользователя и общались между собой. Как так сделать?
Как выбрать (определить сколько пользователей сейчас онлайн) этих пользователей из всех?
Какие технологии использовать?
Где хранить переписку (хоть и временно или как вариант - постоянно) ?

Comment: Где и как угодно. Нет, ну правда.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Часто берут готовое решение для чата. В php перенаправляют  запросы туда и ответы оттуда. При этом появляется возможность сделать участие в чате посторонних (не с вашего сайта), если это надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот небольшой набросок иерархии классов и их взаимодействия. Многие нюансы буду намеренно упускать, но общая идея, думаю, станет Вам понятна.

Структура данных:

```
#таблица пользователей User
id | login | password

#таблица чат-комнат ChatRoom
id | max_user 

#таблица отношений пользователь-чат (многие-ко-многим) UserChat
id | user_id | chat_room_id | joined

#таблица для хранения сообщений в чат комнатах ChatMessage
id | user_chat_room_id | message | posted_at
```

Класс User.php:

```
class User {
    // в классе пользователя реализуем методы логина в систему,
    // получения чат комнат, в которых состоит пользователь и т.д., а также
    // CRUD операции

    /**
    * Отправка нового сообщения в чат
    */
    public function postMessage(ChatRoom $chatRoom, $msg) {
        // Проверка: имеет ли пользователь доступ в комнату?
        if ( $chatRoom->checkUserAccess($this) ) {
            // Если имеет, создаем новое сообщения и сохраняем его в базе
            $chatMsg = new ChatMessage($chatRoom, $user, $msg);
            $chatMsg->save();
        }
    } 

}
```

Класс ChatRoom.php:

```
class ChatRoom {

private $id;
private $maxUser;

public __construct($maxUser) {
    $this->maxUser = $maxUser;
}

public function save() {
// обращение к базе данных, записываем данные в базу
}

// ...реализовываем остальные CRUD-операции..

/**
*Метод проверки имеет ли пользователь доступ к чату
*/
public function checkUserAccess(User $user) {
   $userId = $user->getId();
   $userChat = new UserChat();
   // Делегируем проверку методу модели UserChat, которая ищет в таблице UserChat запись с соответствующими chat_room_id и user_id
   return $userChat->findBy($this->id, $userId);
}

public function getInvitedUsers() {
    // метод находит в базе и возвращает массив приглашенных в комнату пользователей
}

// Пригласить пользователя в чат
public function invite(User $user) {
    // проверяем можно ли пригласить еще одного пользователя в чат
    if ( count($this->getInvitedUsers() < $this->maxUser ) {
        $userChat = new UserChat($this, $user);
        // создается новая запись в таблице UserChat, с user_id приглашенного пользователя и chat_room_id текущей комнаты
        $userChat->save();
    }
}

public function getMessages() {
    // метод возвращает все сообщения из ChatMessages, для текущей комнаты
}

public function getMessagesSince($time) {
    // возвращает все сообщения, отправленные после $time, используется для обновления данных во время разговора
}



}
```

Оставшиеся классы не расписываю - там по большому счету простые *CRUD* операции.
Используя экземпляры этих классов можно собрать простую чат-комнату. Для обновления данных в реальном времени рекомендую почитать про *WebSocket*.
А для не совсем честного реального времени, можно использовать ajax-запрос, который будет получать данные (через метод `ChatRoom::getMessagesSince($time)`) через заданный интервал времени и/или по нажатию на кнопку "обновить".

Тема обширная, поэтому ответил очень "широкими мазками". Хочу также добавить, что в моих примерах кода за запросы к базе данных и логику объектов предметной области отвечают одни и те же классы - так сделано лишь для наглядности, и я настоятельно рекомендую так не делать, а вынести логику работы с базой данных в отдельные объекты.
Надеюсь, что сумел помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно ну прям в "Реальном времени" то копайте в направлении сокетов и node.js 
Иначе у вас выходит, что клиенты должны отправлять запросы на сервер и чекать - "Нет ли для них сообщений"

Comment: Поправочка: вебсокетов. И node.js для этого трогать необязательно.

Answer (score -2):

Не нужен для простого чата PHP, [нужен P2P](http://skylink.io/web/). Можно использовать как нативный webRTC, так и у skylink есть альтернативы, например PeerJS, Pusher etc. Минимальный чат получается ~20 строчек Javascript.

Хранение переписки: localStorage + алгоритм синхронизации. Для расширения этой функциональности действительно может быть полезен сервер, однако для базовых возможностей чата и этого вполне хватает. Более того, Offline-first - принцип проектирования, подразумевающий работоспособность приложения без доступа к серверу. И наращивать возможности нужно постепенно. Обратное - частая ошибка начинающих при проектировании.

Comment: Для надёжного P2P всё равно нужен сервер, будь то TURN или собственный фоллбэк. А WebRTC DataChannel, помнится, нет в Edge, и это очень даже беда.

Comment: Разумеется, нужен. Вот поэтому я и дал ссылку именно на skylink и намекнул что есть другие провайдеры TURN/STUN .  А что же касается кроссбраузерности - такой задачи топикстартером не ставилось, однако очевидно, что для этого решения есть свои применения. Даже промышленные, например, в окружении crosswalk. Так что не понял ваш минус, не лень же ставить.

Comment: Просто у решения через P2P на данный момент проблем даже больше, чем у централизованного на вебсокетах. Потому и минус.

Comment: У централизации свои проблемы. А будущее - за p2p, очевидно. Оно уже работает достаточно хорошо. Уже существует нескольких специализированных провайдеров TURN/STUN. Да, это не про PHP, но WebRTC создано для нормальных современных языков и реализовано в железе и, клянусь бритвой оккама - это самый правильный и простой способ сделать чат.

Comment: Плевать на PHP :) С P2P придётся просто решать ещё больше задач, ими-то автор и интересовался: (а) где хранить историю? (б) как следить за числом пользователей онлайн? (в) кому с кем соединяться? Вы ни на что из этого не ответили.

Comment: Ну это, буквально, другой вопрос.  И кстати, я могу ответить на каждый из этих.

Comment: Не другой. Это есть в вопросе.

Comment: Действительно. Добавил про хранение. А отслеживание пользователей онлайн, соединение и верификация - для webRTC не проблема, это базовая функциональноть протокола + немного смекалки для реализации E2E шифрования.

Comment: ok, но когда вы сейчас или через пару лет будете делать приложения на webRTC, не поленитесь плюсануть обратно )